# loop through a list and create arrays showing all sequences of n in a row, followed by the next iteration in the list

Tags: python

If I have a list, I'm attempting to create a function that will go through the list and create arrays of size n.

For example:

`list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` with `n = 3`

Running the function would generate `[0, 1, 2]`, `[1, 2, 3]`, `[2, 3, 4]` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works for you:

```
x=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]

def lst(lst, n):
    for x in range(len(lst)-(n-1)):
        print(lst[x:x+n])

lst(x,3)
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 4]
[3, 4, 5]
[4, 5, 6]
[5, 6, 7]
[6, 7, 8]
[7, 8, 9]
[8, 9, 10]
[9, 10, 11]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip`  with lists with incremented offsets:

```
lst = list(range(11))
n = 3
out = []
for sub in zip(*[lst[i:] for i in range(n)]):
    out.append(list(sub))
```

Since `zip` stops at the end of the final list, you won’t have any empty values at the end. And in a function:

```
def func(list, n):
    return [[*x] for x in zip(*[list[i:] for i in range(n)])]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write it as a function, you have two inputs:

`input_list` and `n`

Then you should iterate over the list, and make sub-lists with length `n`, i've done this using list `slices`.

```
def print_list(input_list,n):
    for i in range(len(input_list)):
        if len(input_list[i:i+n])==n:
            print(input_list[i:i+n])
```

Here you can find the output of this program with an example :

```
>>> print_list([1,2,3,4,5,6],3)
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 4]
[3, 4, 5]
[4, 5, 6]
```